# Одна авторизация на домене 2-го и 3-го уровня

Tags: php, html, javascript

Занимаюсь разработкой сайтов http://sitev.ru и http://wheel.sitev.ru, на самом деле это один сайт, просто часть сайта вынес в домен 3-го уровня. Написал "вход на сайт" для обоих сайтов (используется один "движок"). Вот только не пойму, почему при входе на 1-ый сайт, я автоматом не регистрируюсь на 2-ом?

Comment: Для вас это один сайт, а вот для браузера это два разных сайта. В общем ниже дело говорят. Куки надо прописывать, чтоб их читали оба сайта. :)

Comment: Добавлю еще к ответу @intro94, что это не только для браузера два разных сайта, но и для системы адресации (DNS). И по сабдомен.домен.зона может оказаться другой сервак, нежели по домен.зона. И трюк с проставлением куков на все пастбище сабдоменов может решить проблему с единой авторизацией приложений разного функционала, когда они физически разбиты по совсем разным адресам.

Answer (score 3):

Я у себя решил этот вопрос закидывая при авторизации на любом из под доменов(или основном домене) куку . Также в коде присутствует проверка наличия куки . Если есть кука и пользователь не авторизован то проводим авторизацию.

Answer (score 3):

Куки (даже если это куки сессии) надо проставлять не для domain.zone, а для .domain.zone (добавить точку в начало), после этого они будут видны на всех поддоменах.